# R node {xml_nodeset} to xml or html

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing, rvest, xml2

Take any hypothetical node generated by `xml2::read_html` / `rvest`, e.g:

```
require(xml2); require(rvest)
doc = read_html('https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html')
e = html_node(doc, '.subtoc')
```

Is there any way to convert `e` back to html?  The closest thing I can do is:

```
xml2::write_html(e, 'e.html')
head(readLines('e.html'))
[1] "<div class=\"subtoc\">"                                               
[2] "<p><strong>Contents</strong></p>"                                     
[3] ""                                                                     
[4] "<ol>"                                                                 
[5] "<li>"                                                                 
[6] "<a class=\"tocxref\" href=\"#h-2.1\">What is the World Wide Web?</a> "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to convert the nodes into characters and then repeat the read_html code.

```
newdoc <-read_html(as.character(e))

write_html(newdoc, e.html)
```

This will create a readable html document.